# Laravel4 API vs bundle

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So I'm using Laravel 4 to write a web application. This web application also has an API. If I was using Laravel 3, I would simply create a bundle. What do I do in Laravel 4?

Comment: It depends. Do you need an API to be accessible by a third party? For an application I'm writing right now, I'm writing it as a package that is used by our application. Once third-parties need access, we just need to add some routes and controllers to use the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a package, which isn't to difficult if you follow the docs. http://four.laravel.com/docs/packages